# Remove space dot(.) special characters from column name from excel to winform checkboxes

Tags: c#, regex

Can anyone help me to solve the problem during upload a excel file to Winforms in C#?

When I upload an Excel file, if any space or . or special characters (_,$,#) exist in an Excel column name (like "ORD. No" or DATE_JOIN, "emp name") then the column will display like "ORDNO" , DATEJOIN in C#.

After uploading an Excel file, I just did following code to get the COLUMN NAME in checkbox with following code

```
for (int c = 0; c < cnt; c++)
{
    cbox = new CheckBox();//cbox checkbox object
    cbox.Text = ds.Tables[0].Columns[c].ColumnName.Trim();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Regex reg = new Regex("[_$#.]"); // your unwanted characters inside the []
cbox.Text = reg.Replace(ds.Tables[0].Columns[c].ColumnName.Trim(), "");
```